# Load then read a multidimensional array - PHP / Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have two tables A & B

```
TableA // (People)
UserID    Name
10         Dan
20         Jane
30         Shelley

TableB // (Pics)
PicID    UserID
100      10
200      10
300      20
```

I want to take everything from Table A and load it into an array and then add arrays for the images within the array but am unsure how to do this:

Currently for Table A I think:

```
$query = "select * from TableA";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $array[] = $row;
    // do another select here to get pics and add data to array multiDimensionally
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Then I'm reading it like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onLoadData
});

function onLoadData(data) {

// Create HTML for the images.
var html = '';

var i = 0, length = data.length, image;

for (; i < length; i++) {

    image = data[i];

    html += '<div class="holder">';
    html += '<div class="name">' + image.Name + '</div>;

    // do another loop here to show images for each person

    html += '</div>';

}
```

Is this the best way to do it and if so, how would I add to the array and then read from it?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then this can be done in another way-

Mysql :

```
$query = "select * from TableA join TableB on TableA.UserID=TableB.UserId order by TableA.UserID asc";
```

And the Jquery part:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: apiURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
       $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
           //alert( key + ": " + value ); //do what ever you want
      });
    }
});
```